# Нужно спрятать спрайт за UI в unity

Tags: unity3d

Нужно спрятать ракету под UI Image и кнопками, но когда я перетаскиваю его вниз, то спрайт лежит поверх UI. Что сделать для этого?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте изменить координату Z(уменьшите или увеличьте)

Comment: я это пытался делать. Бесполезно...

Comment: Что за сцена, что за настройки объектов? Без данной информации ответить нереально.

Comment: согласен с @RiotBr3aker, вы слишком мало дали информации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У компонентов `SpriteRenderer` и `Canvas` есть поля "SortingLayer" - это слой сортировки и "Order in Layer" - это положение внутри этого слоя.

Объекты рисуются каждый кадр поочерёдно согласно этим настройкам. `Canvas` рисует всех своих чайлдов, а `SpriteRenderer` конкретный спрайт. Изменяя эти значения вы можете управлять тем, какой объект будет "ближе к камере"

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно разделить на разные лееры и ближний обьект можно спрятать за дальним. Не смотря на то, что он ближний.